# Can not copy text to textarea using jquery after text is removed from textarea

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea in my html page. It also has a button. When I click on that button i need to copy some text in the text area.

This is working properly.

After i click on copy, If I now remove or edit some text in text area and If i click on copy again text is not getting copied.

Please help.

Below is the HTML code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea cols="20" rows="20" name="mytext" id="mytext">Copy here .... </textarea>

<br>

<input type="button" value= "Copy" onclick="copy();"/>

<script>
function copy(){
    $('#mytext').html(  $('#mytext').html() +  "some sample text message ");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) not `html()` like

```
function copy(){
    $('#mytext').val(  $('#mytext').val() +  "some sample text message ");
}
```